# Problem with USB to RS485 design (CH340B linux)

Tags: rs485, linux

We designed USB to rs485 converter, which is working fine. We designed now software, which is transmitting really lot of data. Baud is 19200.
We are now facing problems, that converter stops receiving/transmitting data after a while (1 or 2 hours). After 1 minute, is everything ok again.
We tried with cheap Chinese USB to RS485 converter, and this doesn't happen. One uses CH340G and other CH340B. We are using CH340B chip.

For design guides we have this 'rule'.:
[image]

So, using 100Ω termination resistor, communication lines are matched impedance of 50Ω.
I'm attaching also schematics of our converter:
[image]

For reference, here is, schematics of Chinese converter which is working fine continuously for months.
[image]
C3 is 10uF (on schematics is wrong value, because of library), all others 3 are 100nF.
Here is also layout of pcb:
[image]

We don't have any idea, how to fix this. Maybe attaching the PNP transistor for automatic flow control on TX line? Both Chinese converters have it. We tried also with FTDI chip, but is not working ok with Linux.

Comment: So are you using this in Linux or where? How do configure the serial port? In Windows there is a separate RS485 handshake mode you can configure.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned. We are using termios, with preconfigured parameters in code. But this is not an issue, because both devices are running with the same config.

Comment: What are D1 and D2?

Comment: Just TVS diodes. And also D3. System has same problems with, or without TVS diodes.

Comment: @douce What's the FTDI chip doing for you under Windows? (You didn't say, above.)

Comment: Seems like you are missing decoupling caps

Comment: Where exactly I'm missing decoupling caps? 
We cannot test it under Windows (too much code writing). With Linux, FTDI chip stops after few seconds and mixes bytes.

Comment: Your D1 and D2 are reversed. As you have them in your schematic you're limiting the voltages on OUTD+ and OUTD- to the diode forward-biased voltage of probably somewhere in the 0.6V-1V range. Similarly, D3 should be a **BiDirectional** TVS, not a Unidirectional one as you have there - It's a perfectly normal condition for D+ to be at a higher voltage than D-, and D3 will also limit this to a 0.6V - 1V diode drop. It's entirely possible that you've damaged your RS485 transceivers by making them drive into those diodes.

Comment: What value are C1, C2 & C4? Where are they placed in relation to IC1 & IC2?

Comment: Ok, thank you @brhans. 
I missed values of Caps. 
C3 is 10uF (on schematics is wrong value, because of library), all others 3 are 100nF.

Comment: I edited first post. All caps are mentioned as decoupling. C1 is taken from recommended design.: https://www.mpja.com/download/35227cpdata.pdf

Comment: C4's placement & routing cause it to not be particularly useful as decoupling for IC1 - you need to move it so that C4-ground and IC1-pin5 have a short path between them. And now that I'm looking closer at your PCB layout it seems like you have a ground plane 'island' stretching underneath IC1 & IC2, connecting to C2 & C3, with only a teeny tiny connection to the rest of the ground net underneath R1! Add more vias - lots of them!

Comment: Problem was in CH340B chip. We are using now CH340G which uses external oscillator and it's working fine now continuously.